# How do I write a good answer on Sports SE?

Tags: discussion, faq, answers

> This is a Canonical Question / FAQ Candidate to help our users write better answers

---

Essentially, good answers come from [good questions](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256/how-do-i-write-a-good-question-on-sports-se). Good answers also cite sources and summarize [quotes](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190/use-of-quotes-in-answers).

Assuming a good question has been asked...the goal is to provide a useful, detailed answer (to any question).

---

### How do I write a good answer on Sports SE?

Comment: Why did this get a downvote? A number of sites are making a post like this right now...

Comment: Not sure how to interpret the question here... Don't get me wrong I definitely welcome the discussion and appreciate the effort, but not sure what it says as a meta question? Are we supposed to chip in and fill in the blanks, a la community wiki?

Comment: @posdef You know these sites are driven by the community. We  determine the standard in writing good questions and answers (through downvotes, comments, and flags)...so let's define the "unwritten" standard.

Comment: @posdef "chip in and fill in the blanks, a la community wiki?" Yes.

Comment: For starters a good answer is informative, detailed and backed up with some reliable reference.

Comment: That's a start. What are examples of and considered informative and detailed? Is a reliable reference a source, an expert, etc? Are links/quotes/etc. from the reference supplemental or dominate the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good answer on Sports Stack Exchange creates unique, direct value. Consider the following while answering a user's question:

- **Is it concise?**  Extra words distract from the point.
- **Is it properly formatted?**  Leverage your answer to create proper emphasis.
- **Is it supported by "authority?"**  Back up claims by referencing sources.  *This is particularly important when discussing rules.*
- **Can I provide a unique perspective?**  Add something new. *If you have insight to add to another user's answer, consider doing so in a [comment](https://sports.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).*
- **Can I share my personal experience(s)?**  Expertise shines through.

---

### Original Response

> People who care about our sites should be focusing on writing great answers that make the internet a truly better place.
>
> [SE Podcast #37](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/11/se-podcast-37/)

Solving the asker's curiousity isn't enough.  A great answer creates unique, direct value that can't really be found anywhere else.

Common characteristics of great answers:

- **Concise**.  Extra words distract from the point.
- **Formatting**.  Leverage it to create proper emphasis.
- **Supported by Authority**.  Back up claims by referencing an authority.  This is particularly important when discussing rules.
- **Unique Perspective**.  Add something new that no one else is talking about.
- **Experience**.  Expertise shines through.  Share pearls of wisdom from personal experience.

Comment: Wonderful. Although this would go beyond sports specifically, it catches a majority of what we want to capture for answers on Sports SE. Thanks for your time and contributions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer with a link to an example.

https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/877/496

I'm not trying to blow my own trumpet at all here but this is the answer I have posted which so far **I** am happiest with.  I feel like I answered the original question, went above the asker's effort expectation and backed everything up with facts.

If I was to state my definition of a good answer I would just cite the answer I posted there.

As with everything here though - I will listen to all arguments for and against.

Comment: I have that [chip](http://sports.stackexchange.com/a/1364/527) on my shoulder as well. This answer took about four hours of research and another two hours to construct it. Answers will vary. Your answer is not a typical answer, but is a great example of an exceptional one. Typically, it does not (and should not) take much time to write an adequate answer.

Comment: @edmastermind29 - I had not seen that answer.  It's quality and certainly not deserving of so few votes.

Comment: Perhaps we can build a list of adequate examples (above and beyond and typical alike). Then, describe commonalities among them.